# Repository for old Dapper Drake Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, repository

I still have a system running on Dapper Drake which i don't want to update.
Now i have to install gcc-3.4 on this system but the Ubuntu repository is shut down and removed.

Is there anyway to get a precompiled package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages you are looking for are still available at [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com) as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks, i've seen that i was still using the URL's for the mirrors in Thailand.

Comment: Update: packages from old releases may now be found at: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/

Answer (score 1):

There still is a repository at `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/`